# Is it possible to change the selected option on the dropbox when you type something from some other text field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a form that has a dropdown that consists of category names and a text field that is intended for typing the category code. What i want is, when i select the category name from the dropdown, it will show the corresponding category code on the text field, and when i type the code in the textfield, the selected option in the dropdown will change according to the code i typed.

I somehow managed to display the code on the textfield when i select from the dropdown, but i cant find a way to change the selected option on the dropdown when i type the code.

here are my codes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $("#manifest_category_id").on("change", function() {
    $("#code_textfield").val($("#manifest_category_id").val());
  });
   $('select').select2().val(alert);
});
</script>
```

This is my dropdown:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.all, :code,:name, :include_blank => '---select waste category---') %>
```

And this is my text field:

```
<%= f.text_field :category_id, :id => "code_textfield" %>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thnx in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible you can take reference from this example . Code is self explanatory. There is one problem with this example if you will add other than alphanumeric value in text field it will break So I will update answer later. if there will not be any value other than alphanumeric then this is perfect example.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#combobox').on('change',function(e){
  if(e.hasOwnProperty('originalEvent') == true){
   $("#textField").val($(this).val());
  }
 });
 
 $('#textField').on('keyup',function(e){
  var regExp = new RegExp("^" + $(this).val() + "$", 'i');
  var matchedValue;
  $("#combobox  option").each(function() {
   matchedValue = regExp.test($(this).val());
   if(matchedValue == true && $(this).val() != ''){
    matchedValue = $(this).val();
    return false
   }  
  });
  $("#combobox").val((matchedValue != null && matchedValue!='' )? matchedValue : $("#combobox").val()).change();
 });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label>Your preferred programming language: </label>
  <select id="combobox" >
    <option value="">Select one...</option>
    <option value="ActionScript">ActionScript</option>
    <option value="AppleScript">AppleScript</option>
    <option value="Asp">Asp</option>
    <option value="BASIC">BASIC</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="Clojure">Clojure</option>
    <option value="COBOL">COBOL</option>
    <option value="ColdFusion">ColdFusion</option>
    <option value="Erlang">Erlang</option>
    <option value="Fortran">Fortran</option>
    <option value="Groovy">Groovy</option>
    <option value="Haskell">Haskell</option>
    <option value="Java">Java</option>
    <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
    <option value="Lisp">Lisp</option>
    <option value="Perl">Perl</option>
    <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
    <option value="Python">Python</option>
    <option value="Ruby">Ruby</option>
    <option value="Scala">Scala</option>
    <option value="Scheme">Scheme</option>
  </select>
</div>
<br/><br/>
<div>
  <label>Your preferred programming language: </label>
  <input type="text" id="textField" />
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

i m helping you through ajax call.

first step: use oninput function it will respond as you start typing in the textfield.

second step: pass textfield value to a ajax page through get function using json or xml

third step : and in response create a drop down thats it.